# Headless Chrome on Azure Cloud fails to indentify some HTML elements

Tags: azure, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to executed Selenium(3.131.0) Headless Chrome Driver(2.36.0) WEB UI automation test cases using Azure DevOps Test Hub using VS2017 C#.NET Core 2.0. It works fine, on the real PC Agent. In case target is Azure cloud Agent (same VS2017 version) Selenium Webdriver fails to detect some of the HTML elements, like Kendo grid for instance. Any suggestion or similar cases ?! Thank You, k

Comment: Some more data on Azure Agent: Google Chrome-68.0.3440.106. With Chromedriver-2.36 some simple test works. With Chromedriver-2.43,  Selenium fails to  start Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some ChromeDriver version changes I found a solution.
Azure DevOps Chrome-68 works reliably with Chromedriver-2.36 
(maybe some fresher version between 36 & 42, did not check).
According to Chrome compatibility table for Chrome-68, 
best version should be ChromeDriver-2.42, but it's not reliable. 
Chromedriver-2.43 fails to start, so it's not compatible at all.

Comment: Unfortunately ChromeDriver-2.36 sometimes fails too. So, it's not a reliable solution.

Comment: Looks like that was Authentication issue with some 3rd party API.